# Where is the petroglyph of Vågan, Norway?

Tags: norway, history, arctic

## What I seek

There is a Norwegian-language wikipedia article titled [Helleristningen i Vågan](https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helleristningen_i_V%C3%A5gan).

[image]

---

## What I found

Unfortunately, there isn't an English version, the Google Translate-ed version is [here](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helleristningen_i_V%25C3%25A5gan).

It says:

> The carving is approx. 200 meters north of highway 80 , approx. two
> kilometers east of Reitan . Information sign at the rest area on site.

There is no source directly quoted for this claim though. The [corresponding Finnish Wikipedia page](https://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A5ganin_kalliopiirrokset) makes the same claim ("Kalliopiirros sijaitsee noin 200 metriä tieltä 52 metrin korkeudessa."), but cites a page saying "The page was not found" ("Siden ble ikke funnet").

The External links ("Eksterne lenker") section of the Norwegian page points to a [kulturminnesok](https://www.kulturminnesok.no/minne?queryString=https://data.kulturminne.no/askeladden/lokalitet/48649) page, with this map:

[image]

Road 80 is there, that's a good sign. The marked location, given the scale in the lower left corner, seems to be closer to 300 than to 200 meters to me.

I align the kulturminnesok map with Google Maps:

[image]

I find that the deer should be the marker I placed on that map above [link to google maps with that area in focus.](https://www.google.com/maps/@67.2981266,14.8995204,14.3z).

---

## What makes me unsure

When I look at Road 80 on Street View in the vicinity of the approximated location, the only clue I find that something might be there is [this narrow path](https://www.google.com/maps/@67.2952065,14.9040211,3a,75y,78h,81.22t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sVDmXDe9ZbzMubcyxTJE5LA!2e0!7i16384!8i8192):

[image]

I don't find any "rest area on site", yet alone "Information sign at the rest area on site", as suggested by the translated Norwegian Wikipedia article.

Satellite view from above:

[image]

Again, nothing which would suggest that there is a historical site there.

Another confusing aspect is that there is a [Vågan Municipality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A5gan), also in [Nordland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordland), but it is in [Lofoten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lofoten), not anywhere near the place I was considering above.

---

## The question

[<sub>that drives us. Dw not that one</sub>](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXeF1rMkpQw&feature=youtu.be&t=113)

The question is, **is the deer painting the Wikipedia articles mentions, actually there?** ie roughly at the location I figured using Google Maps? **Will following that path from Road 80**, which I screenshoted above, **take me to that deer?**

Comment: The Finnish page has GNSS coordinates. The eternal link on the Norwegian page works and is probably what the Finnish page's link should be. The external link's page (translated) that it's 300 m--like you suspect and says the sign is in the field AKA near the petroglyph, so not at the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All other information I can find about the petroglyph point to the same spot that you have found. On an older [official map](https://norgeskart.no/#!?project=norgeskart&layers=1012&zoom=16&lat=7464446.79&lon=495974.16) of the area, a historical site is marked with the symbol ᚱ at the same spot (upper, middle part of the map I linked to).

```
Latitude
67.2975205 degrees
67°17′51.07388″

Longitude   
14.9053096 degrees
14°54′19.11451″
```

At least on that map (published 1969) there is a foot path (dashed line) up to the site starting at the end of a side road, obviously [the road you can see here](https://www.google.de/maps/@67.29612,14.901091,3a,75y,105.94h,79.07t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s01KUCtxvGEqpZ05OHLf9vg!2e0!7i16384!8i8192) on Google Maps.

The turn-off / side road where the path starts is at:

```
NORD    
67.2960665 degrees
67°17′45.83947″

Longitude
14.9011134 degrees
14°54′4.00809″
```

Comment: Note: I pulled the coordinates from the 1969 map. Nordeskart says they're in ETRS89 which should be close to WGS84. The second set, at least, is well off the highway in Google Maps, unfortunately.

Comment: @mkennedy Thank you. I am not sure if the aerial and satellite photography always align perfectly with the maps, but if they do, the site is about 60m east of the coordinates you posted here. You can switch to aerial view on the Norwegian mapping site as well, making it easier to compare the area with Google Maps.

Comment: its cool that they use runes on the old map :) :)